# Can't Find Jupyter Notebook Kernel

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I currently use a Mac. I recently created a new python virtual environment and installed jupyter. When I activate jupyter notebook within the virtual environment, it says it cannot find any python kernels. I have another virtual environment that also has jupyter installed and it works perfectly fine. Can anyone help? Also, I'm not sure where the Kernels are even located on my machine. Library/Jupyter only has a runtime folder.

Answer (score 19):

I need to do 2 things to get this to work:
`conda install -y ipykernel`
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv`

Kind of frustrating and I never see it mentioned much in the docs. Jupyter set up remains a pretty painful process in my opinion. This is from beginning to end, if it helps anyone:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
conda activate myenv
conda install -y -c conda-forge jupyterlab
conda install -y -c anaconda jupyter
conda install -y ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv
```

Comment: Note `python -m` option means 'module', `conda -y` means automatic 'yes' to prompts, `conda -c` means 'channel'

Comment: Thanks! This works even if you've created a virtual env using `venv` or something: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name name_of_venv`.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing nb_conda in your environment, by going to your command line `conda activate` your environment and `conda install nb_conda`. Make sure you also have `ipykernel` installed in your environment, then deactivate and reactivate your environment and try again.

Comment: As of 14 Jul 2021, this approach no longer works.

Comment: it just worked for me. I did not see all the kernels in my jupyter env. But after doing "conda install nb_conda" I started seeing all the kernels. So, it is worth the try still and should not be ruled as not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the pip, you can install ipykernel package:

```
pip install ipykernel
```